# Unable to communicate between docker containers

Tags: docker

We are running two docker containers with network as host for each container, We are able to communicate to container from outside world, but we are not able to communicate between the containers.

Is there a way to configure docker network so that containers can communication among themselves as well as outside world.

Comment: I think Docker link what you are looking for.

Comment: @PumpkinSeed: docker network seems to have replaced docker link, what I am trying to understand is how to connect a docker network to outside world

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a docker container to use "host" networking, you completely remove the docker networking stack, including the container to container networking and built in dns discovery. Everything you see in the container's network is identical to what you see on the host. So another container listening on localhost is visible on 127.0.0.1 from the host and from other containers with host networking.

This is not the recommended way to run docker containers in most scenarios. You typically create a docker network for a group of containers, start those containers on that docker network, and then refer to the other containers by their container name.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my question, I am able to communicate between containers using docker0 network (default network), and to map select ports of container to outside world I am using -p mapping to map from container port to host port.

as @BMitch suggested a separate network to connect only the containers that need inter container comm is better than using docker0 as all containers without any explicit network configuration connect to docker0.